# Switch statement in LaTeX using package pseudocode

Tags: pseudocode

I am using `\usepackage{pseudocode}` in LaTeX for writing pseudocode.

How to write **switch** statement using this package?

I write more 90% pseudocode using the package **pseudocode**. In function Validate i want to write **switch** Statement.

```
\PROCEDURE{Validate}{location1,location2}
l1 \GETS 0 \\
l2 \GETS 0 \\
validate \GETS true \\
\IF board[location1] \neq 0 \THEN
    \BEGIN 
    l1 \GETS board[location1]
    l2 \GETS board[location2]
    \IF l1 + l2 is odd and l2 \neq 0 \THEN
        validate \GETS false
    \ELSE
        \BEGIN
            %\SWITCH  here i want to write switch statement
                   %\BEGIN

            %\END
        \END
    \END

 \RETURN {validate}\\
 \ENDPROCEDURE
```

I can find add switch statement in pseudocode using other packages like algorithmicx and algorithm. There is any way to add switch statement using **pseudocode** **package** ?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3741013/using-latex-algorithmic-package-for-switch-statement

Answer (score 4):

I'm really not sure whether this is what you're after, but it's a first go:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,pseudocode}% http://ctan.org/pkg/{amsmath,pseudocode}
\newcommand{\algvar}[1]{\text{\ttfamily\upshape#1}}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\SWITCH}{\mbox{\bfseries switch }}
\renewcommand{\CASE}{\mbox{ \bfseries case }}
\newcommand{\CASEELSE}{\mbox{ \bfseries else }}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{pseudocode}{Validate}{\algvar{location1}, \algvar{location2}}
    \PROCEDURE{Validate}{\algvar{location1}, \algvar{location2}}
    l_1 \GETS 0 \\
    l_2 \GETS 0 \\
    \algvar{validate} \GETS \TRUE \\
    \IF \algvar{board}[\algvar{location1}] \neq 0 \THEN
        \BEGIN 
        l_1 \GETS \algvar{board}[\algvar{location1}] \\
        l_2 \GETS \algvar{board}[\algvar{location2}] \\
        \IF (l_1 + l_2 \text{ is odd}) \AND (l_2 \neq 0) \THEN
            \algvar{validate} \GETS \FALSE
        \ELSE
            \BEGIN
                \SWITCH i
                    \BEGIN
                        \CASE 1 \text{ Something 1} \\
                        \CASE 2 \text{ Something 2} \\
                        \CASE 3 \text{ Something 3} \\
                        \CASE 4 \text{ Something 4} \\
                        \CASEELSE \text{ Something else}
                    \END
            \END
        \END \\
        \RETURN {\algvar{validate}} \\
    \ENDPROCEDURE
\end{pseudocode}
\end{document}
```

The constructions used by [`pseudocode`](http://ctan.org/pkg/pseudocode) is based on `array`s, so it's easily modifiable. However, it depends on what you're after in terms of the look of a `\SWITCH` command, in terms of placement, alignment and justification.